# Integration of Dynamic CRM with Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have to integrate microsoft dynamice CRM with windows phone 8. I haven't really found any solution after trying for last couple of days. Any sample example will be helpful. We are using LiveId as authentication.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link, there is also an example to download:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/11/02/building-clients-for-windows-phone-and-windows-8-rt.aspx

However my suggestion is to create a Web Service that will act as a bridge between CRM and your Windows Phone app instead to connect directy to CRM.

Comment: We don't have any option to have a bridge WCF service.

Comment: so your only solution is to follow the example included in the post I linked

Comment: I downloaded the sample but its not working for me. I am not able to login itself. I changed the service path and username and password